# Rerendering a component - ReactJS, Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

After calling `canBookSlot` I want to update the `slotsList` I figure i have to make a new Axios request, can i reuse the useEffect whitin the `then()` method to rerender the component with updated properties or is there any other smart way of doing it without rewriting the Axios request?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/get/week1/ex").then((response) => {
      setSlotsList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  let userDetailsString = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
  const userDetailsObj = JSON.parse(userDetailsString);

  const canBookSlot = (id) => {
    if (userDetailsObj.canBook != 0) {
      Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/book/week1/ex", {
        room: userDetailsObj.room,
        id: id.id + 1,
      }).then(); // update the slotsList
    }
  };
```

**EDIT:**

The userDetailsObj is an object from another component, It isn't the same object as the ones in `slotList` how do i go about rerendering `userDetailsObj`

```
    const updateData = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/get/week1/ex").then((response) => {
      setSlotsList(response.data);
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    updateData();
  }, []);

  let userDetailsString = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
  let userDetailsObj = JSON.parse(userDetailsString);

  const canBookSlot = (id) => {
    if (userDetailsObj.canBook != 0) { // Always true 
      Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/book/week1/ex", {
        room: userDetailsObj.room,
        id: id.id + 1,
      }).then(() => updateData())
    }
  };
```

Comment: you can use useEffect with dependency array and add your slotlist in it. so whenever slotlist changes, use effect will rerun. Keep in mind, when your use effect runs, it runs all the functions inside use effect. also with new React versions, when state is updated, it should re-run the code in the same page. So depending on your needs, you can adopt an approach that you can reuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create common function and reuse when you want to call that axios api and update the data.

```
updateData = () => {
  Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/get/week1/ex").then((response) 
 => {
     setSlotsList(response.data);
   });
}

useEffect(() => {
 updatedData();
}, []);

let userDetailsString = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
const userDetailsObj = JSON.parse(userDetailsString);

const canBookSlot = (id) => {
if (userDetailsObj.canBook != 0) {
  Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/book/week1/ex", {
    room: userDetailsObj.room,
    id: id.id + 1,
  }).then(() => updateData()); // update the slotsList
}
};
```

Comment: That worked, but the values in `userDetailsObjs` haven't changed. Is there anywatyto rerender `userDetailsObj`?

Comment: I think you need to update the state, can you please provide updated code?

Comment: I updated the post with relevant code

Comment: userDetailsObj is a localstorageObject so you have to update manually by logic then it works.